# Next.js - Link does not work in production

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

I use NextJS 9.1.3 and I am generating a navigation in my project using the following code:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Navigation = () => {
  const navPoints = [
    {
      id: 0,
      key: '/index',
      icon: 'info',
      title: 'Testpage',
      path: '/',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      key: '/helloworld',
      icon: 'info',
      title: 'Hello World',
      path: '/helloworld',
    },
  ];

  const propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.function,
    href: PropTypes.string,
    icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  const defaultProps = {
    onClick: Function.prototype,
    href: '',
  };


  const CustomNavPoint = React.forwardRef(
    ({
      onClick, href, icon, title,
    }, ref) => (
      <a href={href} onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
        <Icon type={icon} />
        {title}
      </a>
    ),
  );
  CustomNavPoint.propTypes = propTypes;
  CustomNavPoint.defaultProps = defaultProps;
  CustomNavPoint.displayName = 'CustomNavPoint';

  const router = useRouter();
  const currentRoute = router.pathname;
  return (
    <Menu
      selectedKeys={[currentRoute === '/' ? '/index' : currentRoute]}
      mode="horizontal"
      overflowedIndicator={<Icon type="bars" />}
    >
      {navPoints && navPoints.length
        ? navPoints.map((el) => (
          <Menu.Item key={el.key} title={el.title}>
            <Link href={el.path} passHref>
              <CustomNavPoint icon={el.icon} href={el.path} title={el.title} />
            </Link>
          </Menu.Item>
        ))
        : null}
    </Menu>
  );
};
export default Navigation;
```

In development mode it runs perfectly, but if I do:

```
yarn build


yarn export (next export)
```

then the **Links won't work in the production build.**

I have read that passHref is important as well as the click function, but the navigation points do not work.

Although the anker tag gets the correct path:

[image: HTML of the navpoint]

What is the problem with that, can someone help here ?

Comment: Can you try removing the `href` in the element under the Link tag? I had this problem before and I remember doing this.

Comment: @Edrian tried that, did not work :(

Comment: I had same issue and fixed it by renaming the file name to lowercase. Register.js to register.js, then worked